# Modelling against "day" or "day^2" in to look at change over time?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multivariate-regression

I'm a masters student trying to model changes in behaviour, heart rate variation and faecal cortisol as welfare measures in sheep over the course of 22 days. Days -4 to -1 is used as baseline, day 0 has no measures as they were in surgery and days 1 to 17 are what I'm interested in.

For behaviour my supervisor told me not to look at each day as a factor individually because there is bound to be some false positives for significance, but to divide them into blocks of four or five to look at larger changes. This worked pretty well to model as a mixed model in lme4. She also told me to get someone else to check my stats as she doesn't know R. The university only started teaching it last year.

This other person told me I should plot my changes against time as a regression and look at my plots for explanations which I can do with lmer(). But he also said I should probably model against days squared because that would account better for the curves on my plots (there's a nice dip in most of my plots on day 1-3 or so indicating pain/stress). This seemed to make sense at the time but now I'm confused. Why would it make sense to model day squared rather than day alone? Modelling frequency of behaviours against type of behaviour and day gives the best fit model and perfectly distributed residuals. Using "DaySq" rather than "Day" gives slightly different values but almost identical residuals.

This is the start of my dataset for behaviour. It goes down to about 500 lines.

```
      Behaviour Sheep Day DaySq Block Observed Frequency
1      Standing     2  -4    16     0       49  71.01449
2         Lying     2  -4    16     0       12  17.39130
3        Eating     2  -4    16     0       36  52.17391
4    Ruminating     2  -4    16     0       16  23.18841
5 Moving in pen     2  -4    16     0        0   0.00000
6  XDisturbance     2  -4    16     0        9  13.04348
```

This is the model I used:

```
lmer(data = behdata2, Frequency ~ Behaviour * Day + (1|Sheep))
```

Comment: A quadratic term will not handle a dip on the first three days out of 22 days. That's why your results change little.  For a much better alternative, [search this site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+spline+user%3A4253) for Frank Harrell's many references to using *splines* in regression models.

Comment: That does make sense... Not sure I'm finding much I can make sense of in those references though. I'm pretty much a beginner at R and more heavy stats. Would it make sense to use a non-linear mixed model instead? I've been trying to fit it but not making much headway.

Comment: The non-linear model would make sense if you had an underlying theory to suggest a mathematical form of the response.  Otherwise, splines provide flexible tools to explore the shape of the response.